# Getting single handle faucet off with no set screw

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to fix a leaky single handle faucet but I cannot find a set screw or really any way to get the handle off. I tried prying off and just pulling. There are no screws under or behind the lever. Any advice?
[image: silver single handle faucet]

Comment: Is there any identifying name maybe under the spout? How about looking into the spout for a screw? Longshot but...

Comment: look into the spout

Comment: what's that blemish under the lever.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the screw is from underneath and the assembly needs removing first.

Had a similar tap to deal with and the top slid into the body - with several o rings and was held in place by a set screw from the base. Only way was to remove it from the sink first.

Comment: really bad answer.

Comment: @ojait shame you were not there to deal with my tap in a professional; and expert manner.